# Translation of SpringBoot @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

In my code I have an interface with an `updatePerson(Age age, Address address)`. This method is being called from 3 different controllers. Now because of some requirement in 1 of the controller I had to pass an additional field to this method as `updatePerson(Age age, Address address, Experience experience)`.

In order to avoid passing `updatePerson(Age age, Address address, null)` in the 2 other controllers, I thought of converting this method as a default method in my interface and internally calling the other method. So my interface now looks like:

```
public interface PersonService
{
   default PersonDO updatePerson(Age age, Address address) {
     return updatePerson(Age age, Address address, null);
   }

   PersonDO updatePerson(Age age, Address address, Experience experience);
}
```

Now the issue is :
In the implementation of this interface, the original `updatePerson` was annotated with `@Transactional`. I know if a normal method calls a method annotated with `@Transactional`, the transaction doesn't work as it is taken care of by spring.

So in the implementation now I am having `updatePerson(Age age, Address address, Experience experience)` annotated with @Transactional.

The controller which directly calls `updatePerson(Age age, Address address, Experience experience)` , the execution will happen in a transaction. But I am not sure what happens when the controller which calls the `default updatePerson(Age age, Address address)` and it internally calls implemented method ? Does the execution still happens in a transaction or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@Transactional` to default method and therefore it will be inside transaction also

```
@Transactional    
default PersonDO updatePerson(Age age, Address address) {
  return updatePerson(Age age, Address address, null);
}
```

Comment: So this means that my doubt was correct ? The execution will not happen in a `Transaction` in my original code ?

Comment: @IllegalSkillsException your problem is because you call method on the same class, so  inner `@Transactional` method won't work as transaction